# how to push separating a word from the text?

Tags: c++

I have a string array and I have push name off this array.

array:

```
string list_full[3];

list_full[0]: name1 family1

list_full[1]: name2 family2

list_full[2]: name2 family2
```

I want get this list:

```
name1
name2
name3
```

so, i use this code:

```
string name;
for(count=0; count<3; count++)
{
    getline(list_full[count], name,' ');
    cout<<name<<endl;
}
```

but this not working and get this error:

no matching function for call to

```
getline(std::string&, std::string&, char)
```

Comment: Just so you know, if you have an array of length `[3]`, then the valid indexes are `[0]`, `[1]`, and `[2]`. If you index `[3]` it will be out of range and result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// ...

for (auto const & s : list_full)
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::string token;
    if (iss >> token)
    {
        std::cout << token << '\n';
    }
}
```

Or in C++03:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
{
    std::istringstream iss(list_full[i]);
    // ...
```

Comment: get error of for(....): a function-definition is not allowed here before ':' token

Comment: I can not use this method. Please choose another method introduced

Comment: @user3636779: Just replace the loop statement: `for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i)`, and use `list_full[i]` in place of `s`...

Comment: i want use std::vector<std::string> list_full. i have string list_full[].

Comment: @user3636779: same difference. Try it before you complain.